# writing data with spark streaming

Tags: hive, spark-streaming

I am consuming data from kafka using spark streaming. When I try to write the data to hdfs using method saveAsHadoopFiles as in the code, it creates a directory (named Date-Timestamp.txt) every minute with an empty _SUCCESS file in each of them. It is able to print the data that it receives but not saving it properly. I want it to write files instead of directories with correct data. Any pointers to whats going wrong here.

I will want the data to be ultimately stored in a hive table.
Will be good if someone can suggest a better method of writing this data into a hive table?

```
 public static void main(String args[]){
    SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local[2]").setAppName("LocationCoordinates");
    JavaStreamingContext jssc = new JavaStreamingContext(conf, Durations.minutes(1));
    Map<String,Integer> topicMap = new HashMap<String,Integer>();
    topicMap.put("test",1);
    JavaPairReceiverInputDStream<String, String> kafkaStream =
            KafkaUtils.createStream(jssc,
                    "ec2-54-174-149-226.compute-1.amazonaws.com:2181", "location_group", topicMap);
    String date = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy").format(new Date());
    kafkaStream.print();
    kafkaStream.saveAsHadoopFiles("hdfs:/user/19491/iotdata/" + date + "-", "txt", Text.class,Text.class, TextOutputFormat.class);
    jssc.start();
    jssc.awaitTermination();

}
```

Comment: Anshuman could you post the solution if you were able to get past your problem. Thanks!

Comment: Did u get a way to do that. I have the same problem.

Comment: Bump. I am also having a similar problem.